# How to solve Rails duplicate url (canonical) issue ? redirect /example to /example/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I noticed that in my rails app, `example.com/page` is not redirecting to `example.com/page/` , I am assuming this is default behavior but is not good from search engine point of view as they look it as two different pages. How can I do 301 redirect from `/page` to `/page/` ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is long overdue, but you should not redirect
The best method is to make sure there is a canonical ref when addressing both pages

```
<link href="https://example.com/page/" rel="canonical">
```

If the /page is a collection, then it is a convention to add '/' as a post-fix

This will mark search engines that when the page '**https://example.com/page**' as actually **https://example.com/page/**

Use the [canonical-rails](https://github.com/jumph4x/canonical-rails) in order to do it automatically in RoR

Answer (score 0):

```
get '/page' => redirect('/page/')
```

Comment: Hi @declan - but there are hundreds of such pages, do I need to do this manually for all or is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: @iCyborg - you're saying for every page in your app, you want it to redirect from `/page` to `/page/`?

Comment: right, so for every /page, /example, /widgets/blue, I want them to be /page/, /example/ and /widgets/blue/

Comment: Hi @declan - well I am also getting infinte loop error. where should I put this get 'page' ... code ? before resource :page or after resource :page ?

Comment: See my answer bellow