# How to redirect url /example to /example/ in Ruby on Rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I has asked this earlier [How to solve Rails duplicate url (canonical) issue ? redirect /example to /example/](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16932211/692622) and was told to use

```
get '/page' => redirect('/page/')
```

but I have hundreds of such page and this is not a very scalable solution. In apache I uses .htaccess since I am using phusion passenger, so do we have some solution ? or any routes.rb way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can have all your urls ends with a trailing slash by setting `:trailing_slash` to true in your application.rb

`config.action_controller.default_url_options = { :trailing_slash => true }`

A related post can be found here: [How to make Rails do not ignore trailing slashes in the routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486758/how-to-make-rails-do-not-ignore-trailing-slashes-in-the-routes)

Comment: Hi Roro, I have put this in config/application.rb and have restarted the server still /page is not redirecting to /page/ ? any idea how I can debug this ? is there anything I am missing ?

Comment: This option will automatically add trailing slash to your urls if you're using UrlHelper like `link_to` tags. It won't redirect /page to /page/ directly, that would be something that deals with server-end settings. Have you done this with your .htaccess? http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/trailing-slash/

Comment: Hi @rorofromfrance - well I am using phusionpassenger so will a .htaccess file work ?